# what mi_command is used to get server time and date in opensips?

Tags: opensips

How can I get server date and time in Opensips,through MI_commands and how can I calculate call duration in Opensips??

$message= ":dlg_list_ctx:\n\n"

thanks

Comment: were you able to calculate your call durations after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At script level, you can print the current time with **$Ts** (Unix timestamp).

Additional information about the current server time can be fetched with:

```
opensipsctl fifo uptime
```

From what I see, you are trying to write a script that monitors the duration of all your calls. For this, you could use the *timestart::* field of `opensipsctl fifo dlg_list_ctx` and figure out the duration of that call.